# What is efficient way of handling filtering criteria, ( Read Operations )?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, cqrs

I have a situation in my backend. Using Nestjs along with typeorm, Following CQRS pattern in code.

I have various scenarios in codebase where I have to filter table and retrieve the data (entities). The problem is the filtering criteria is dynamic.
E.g.
I have a table college with fields (id uuid, name, address, speciality_field (mechanical, automobile, CS, Electrical), owner_group) etc
Now there are various scenarios in code where I have to filter college entity with name, sometimes id, sometimes speciality_field + address.

Solutions I tried :
Now i can create different query for each of the criteria and QueryHandler for each of those query

This will soon create a lot of queries in my codebase and make me loose track of them, giving birth to code redundancy or even dead code

Then I decided to come up with another solution which is having a single query handler but with flexible/ dynamic parameters as depicted below

query definition

```
export class GetCollegesQuery {
  constructor(public readonly queryData : Record<string,any>[]){}
}
```

queryHandler

```
@QueryHandler(GetCollegesQuery)
export class GetCollegesQueryHandler implements IQueryHandler<GetCollegesQuery> {
   async execute(query: GetCollegesQuery): Promise<any> {
    const collegeRepository = dataSource.getRepository(College);

    const colleges = await collegeRepository.find({
      where : query.queryData
    })
    if (!colleges.length) {
      return new NotFoundException();
    }

    return colleges;
  }
}
```

sample usecase

```
@Get()
  async getBranches(
    @Query('speciality') speciality: string,
    @Query('location') location: string,
 ){
    return await this.queryBus.execute(new GetBranchesQuery([{speciality : speciality}, {location : address }]));
 }
```

Question
This is just something i came up with and not sure if this is the best way to solve it.

is there any design pattern or approach to tackle this ???

Comment: Remove `Promise<any>` and leverage type inference